# Windows7 NFS with linux server

Tags: linux, windows, nfs

I have an Ubuntu server and want to access its web folder (**/var/www**).
What I done:

installed *nfs-kernel-server*, *nfs-common* and *portmap* (as in faq)

Setted up */etc/exports*:

*/var/www 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0(rw,no_roow_squash,async,subtree_check)*

Then: **sudo exportfs -ra**

Then: **sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernle-server restart**

I checked, if all works on same machine: **sudo 192.168.1.101:/var/www /mnt/test**

Then accessed **/mnt/test** and seen that all data present and all ok.

Next, I tried to connect this folder to windows7 using NFS client:

First, I checked, that linux exported path successfully:

**showmount -e 192.168.1.101**
*/var/www                           192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0*

All ok, go to mount:
**mount -o anon 192.168.1.101:/var/www z:**

Console said, that all success.. but. I cant access drive Z (drive exists in the system and point to right folder).
When I try to access drive Z my Explorer just going to sleep and then say that timeout expired.

Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking you'll need to set up [User Name Mapping](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463218.aspx).

Comment: nfsd can work either with user names or ip addresses. User name mapping dont solve problem. Anyway I tried to assign unix user (with net use) but without success.
I solved problem by installing Samba server. Thank you for answer.